# Is there a fast way to select item from array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects

I have an array:

```
[
    {
        key: 'some key',
        value: 'some value'
    }, {
        ...
    }, ...
]
```

Is there any simple way to get a certain element of this array without iterating through it and comparing each actual key with desired one?

I currently have a function

```
var select = function(what, from) {
    for (var i in from) {
        if (from[i].key == what) {
            return from[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

I believe there's a better way to handle it.

Comment: *".. certain element of this array without iterating through it .."*: Nah! Not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **no**. There are lots of options to make your code cleaner - like all of the above - but you are still going to have to iterate through them one by one.

You can do 2 things to make it better:

**Convert to Map**

If you are going to do the search more than once or twice, then convert it to a map of the keys, so at least each subsequent lookup is O(1) instead of O(n). A number of answers suggested that - I use it a lot in my own code - but here is a basic version (there is a shorthand un underscore/lodash):

```
var i, hash = {};
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  hash[arr[i].key] = arr[i].value;
}
```

Then for all future lookups it is a simple:

```
var value = hash[key];
```

**Search Algorithms**

If it needs to stay as an array for whatever reason, and you have some knowledge about what that array's values will be like, you can use all sorts of search algorithms. Cycling through them one by one is good for an even distribution, but will still be O(n), which will, on average require cycling through half the array (n/2) each time.

But search algorithms are beyond this post...

Answer (score 1):

You were close. This would be the *fastest* form in this particular case:

```
var select = function(key, expected, from) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < from.length; i += 1) {
        if (from[i][key] === expected) {
            return from[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
};

select('thing', 'foo', [{thing: 'foo'}]);
// => {thing: 'foo'}
```

But do you require maximum speed? Or would a more elegant, general-purpose solution suit you? If so, use a predicate:

```
var find = function (array, predicate) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if (predicate(array[i])) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
};

// Find, in an array, an item which passes the following truth test.
find([{thing: 'foo'}], function (item) {
    return item.thing === 'foo';
});
// => {thing: 'foo'}
```

If you don't like writing boilerplate utility code like this, I recommend leveraging a library like lodash. [It has a find method already](https://lodash.com/docs#find) and it's faster and more powerful than anything we could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using modern browsers, this should do the magic:

```
function include(arr,obj) {
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}
```

or in jquery

```
$.inArray(value, array)
```

In response to your comment, check this [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/arrays/), this will also address your problem in the comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to use it. For example, `[1, 2, 3].indexOf(1)` returns `0` while `[{a: 1}, {a: 2}].indexOf({a: 1})` returns `-1`. How should I use `indexOf` to find index of non-primitive within array?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, however, if you alter your structure to use properties it will be much faster. Any other approach will require iteration over the array and will therefore always be less efficient than the below.

```
var keyValueObj = {
  someKey: 'someValue',
  nextKey: 'nextValue'
}

// represents 'someValue'
keyValueObj['someKey']
```

Answer (score 0):

If your keys are strings use them as object properties instead of an array of objects

If your keys are objects use [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your array into a map, which is, by design, good for quick and effective lookup:

```
{
    'some key': {
        value: 'some value'
    },
    'some other key': {
        value: 'some other value'
    },
}
```

Then your `select` function would be as short as

```
var select = function(what, from) {
    return from[what];
};
```

If you expect return value of the `select()` to still have the `.key` property (which is redundant, as the caller already knows it as `what`), it is easy to achieve by either keeping the `key` property in map elements, or auto-adding in in `select()` before returning.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run this function very often, I would recommend creating an index:

```
var yourItemList = [{...}],
    select = (function (items) {
        var i = 0,
            l = items.length,
            preparedItems = {};

        for (; i < l; ++i) {
            preparedItems[items[i].key] = items[i].value;
        }

        return function (key) {
            return preparedItems[key];
        };
    }(yourItemList));
```

This way you only iterate once on the item list. After that every `select('theKeyYouNeed')` just uses the mapped "index".

Answer (score -1):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) array. It is build in Array method so you don't need to declare other helper functions

```
var arr = [
    {
        key: 'some key',
        value: 'some value'
    }, {
        key: 'some key1',
        value: 'some value'
    }
];

arr = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.key === 'some key'
});
```

Now `arr` has only first object (because its key equal to 'some key'). Object that you find is `arr[0]`.

You can use `find()` instead of `filter()` when you need just one object. Note, that `find()` is part of ES6 and has no support in all major browsers

Comment: DV wasn't warranted. Question is talking about retrieving item. Doesn't matter if that item is one array element or the content. +1.